# Should each law that is used in a proof be explicitly stated?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Here is an example proof:

Theorem: $B\cup \left(\cap F\right)=\cap _{A\in F}\left(B\cup A\right)$
Proof.
Suppose $a\in B\cup \left(\cap F\right)$.
Then, $a\in B\cup \left(\cap F\right)$
iff $a\in B\vee a\in \cap F$
iff $a\in B\vee \forall A\in F\left(a\in A\right)$
iff $\forall A\in F\left(a\in B\vee a\in A\right)$
iff $\forall A\in F\left(a\in B\cup A\right)$
iff $a\in \cap _{A\in F}\left(B\cup A\right)$
Since $a$ was arbitrary, $B\cup \left(\cap F\right)=\cap _{A\in F}\left(B\cup A\right)$

Do I need to state each law that im applying to the statements?
For example I dont know the name of the law that allows me to do this:
$a\in B\vee \forall A\in F\left(a\in A\right)$
$\leftrightarrow$
$\forall A\in F\left(a\in B\vee a\in A\right)$

But i just know its true from my exprience with quantifiers and logical symbols.
And if you are reading a complicated proof like that you should know that those statements are equal.

Comment: No - you should leave enough of a trail for your reader to follow, but explaining every single step is laborious (and, in my opinion, annoying). I should also remark that using just symbols also hurts a bit and makes it difficult to follow.

Comment: Writing out the reasoning for each step is for your sake, when learning . Published  Proofs don't explain every step.